# XPages OpenLog Logger - ErrorDoc

Tags: xpages

First of all thanks to Paul S Withers for his work:

https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger

I would like to use his logger (v8.0), but after some tests, I have to deal with one strange behaviour concerning the error document reference.

**Here an example:**

After logging an error or event including a **doc** reference e.g.:

```
OpenLogUtil.logEvent(new Throwable(), "This is a Java message with Doc", Level.INFO, doc);
```

all following logging calls - without an explicit doc parameter - now referencing the document of the prior call, e.g.:

```
openLogBean.addError(e, this);
OpenLogUtil.logError(e);
etc...
```

**OpenLog Database - Entries:**

[image]

---

[image]

**UPDATE:**

If you are logging from two different databases, the logging will crash with the following exceptions:

```
HTTP JVM: XOL_DEBUG error: Notes error 4091: Invalid universal id
HTTP JVM: XOL_DEBUG error trace: NotesException: Invalid universal id
HTTP JVM: XOL_DEBUG error trace: NotesException: Object has been removed or recycled
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mea culpa, it's re-using the same OpenLogItem. I suspect, because it's scoped to the `session`, the 4091 error will occur. Please try this version https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/XPages%20OpenLog%20Logger/releases/94080D45393E3DC88525835100495C88